# List index out of range in loop

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

Im getting an error for list index being out of range. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

```
def filter_list(l):
  for x in range(0, len(l)):
     if type(l[x]) is str:
       del l[x]
  return l
```

Comment: Do not modify a list while you are looping over it.

Comment: @alaniwi I have a good dupe for this...

Comment: Though you would get away with it if you looped in the reverse direction `range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1)`

Comment: @Nick Ah yes, good spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `del` to delete the item in the list, the list actually shortens and it seems like that is what is causing the problem.

If you would like to filter lists, you could use list comprehensions like so:

```
def filter(l):
    return [item for item in l if type(item) is not str]
```

Usually, when looping over lists, it is good practice not to delete or insert new items.

Hope this helped

Comment: Or just use the builtin `filter` function

Comment: It's bad practice to overload built-in function names.

Answer (score 0):

You should not definitely change a `list` while iterating over it. It is very bad practise... it can lead to a whole lot of errors for you. Either you should create a `copy` of use something else, as list comprehension:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [x for x in l if type(x) is not str]

print(filter_list([1, 4, 5, 's', 'demo'])) # Prints [1, 4, 5]
```